# Infinite recursion with issubclass(int, Container) in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I was trying to test for if an input was a Container and I came across this weird behavior where if you ask if an `int`, `float`, `bool` is a subclass of either `typing.Container` or `collections.abc.Container` (e.g. `issubclass(int, typing.Container)` and it returns `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Shouldn't it just return `False`?

Comment: The specific version of python you are using would be relevant. I get `False` in 3.5.1

Comment: It works for me on Python 3.5.1. I imagine this is a bug.

Comment: is it possible you are using jython? there is a [reported bug for jython](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2055) that seems related.

Comment: As well as the version, can you post code that reproduces the error when run in isolation? As in, if you copy-paste the code into a file and run `python thatfile`, you get the RecursionError? I'd ordinarily ask for the stack trace, but if it's a RecursionError, that might be thousands of lines. (If it isn't thousands of lines, please post the stack trace too.)

Comment: Should have checked this myself, but if I open another instance it is fine. I am in Ipython 4.1.2 using Python 3.5.1 from Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit). Not sure what I could have done to cause this though. And yes the stack trace is very large.